# General image processing model

Tags: magento2, image

Is there a general class that deals with image processing (mainly resizing) that just receives a path to an image, some parameters and processes and saves the image somewhere and returns the new path?
I need this to make it work for images related to my custom entities
Something like the image helper for products `Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image` but this looks very complicated to replicate as it's tightly coupled to the product entity.

If such a class exists in the core, I would appreciate and example on how to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this factory class

```
\Magento\Framework\Image\AdapterFactory
```

For example if you initialize this class in your constructor you can use the below functionality.

```
public function __construct(                 
    \Magento\Framework\Image\AdapterFactory $imageFactory         
) {                      
    $this->imageFactory = $imageFactory;         
}

public function functionName($absolutePath)
{
   $imageProcessor = $this->imageFactory->create();         
   $imageProcessor->open($absolutePath);
   $imageProcessor->constrainOnly(TRUE);         
   $imageProcessor->keepTransparency(TRUE);         
   $imageProcessor->keepFrame(FALSE);         
   $imageProcessor->keepAspectRatio(TRUE);         
   $imageProcessor->resize(100, 100);
   $imageProcessor->save($this->destination);

   // And maybe here return the $this->destination property?
   return $this->destination;
}
```

For more functionality you can take a look in this class

```
Magento\Framework\Image\Adapter\AbstractAdapter
```

I would personally wrap this whole logic in a try catch block.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a try

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are looking for `\Magento\Framework\Image`

Comment: I might. Do you also have an example on how to use?